# How can I unpivot a table twice?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I need help with unpivot of a table. I have a table in a similar structure like this (UserRoles are nullable, in fact the date will not be filled)

```
Object  User_RoleX  User_RoleY User_RoleZ RoleX_Date RoleY_Date
======  =========== ========== ========== ========== ==========
O1      User 1      User 2     User 3     2014-12-08 2013-12-09
O2      NULL        User 1     User 2     NULL       2013-12-09
O3      User 1      NULL       User 1     2014-12-08 NULL
```

I unpivot this table with following command:

```
unpivot(Username for Role in ([User_RoleX], [User_RoleY], [User_RoleZ])) as result
```

And get the following result: (I get this, because the Datecolumns came to this table later, and the unpivot command was not designed for these date columns)

```
Object  Username   Role        RoleX_Date  RoleY_Date
======  ========== ==========  ==========  ============
O1      User1      X           2014-12-08  2013-12-09
O1      User2      Y           2014-12-08  2013-12-09
O1      User3      Z           2014-12-08  2013-12-09

O2      User1      Y           NULL        2013-12-09
O2      User2      Z           NULL        2013-12-09

O3      User1      X           2014-12-08  NULL
O3      User1      Z           2014-12-08  NULL
```

What I want as a result is following, but i don't get this with unpivot command (Role Z doesn't have a date)

```
Object  Username   Role        Date 
======  ========== ==========  ========== 
O1      User1      X           2014-12-08 
O1      User2      Y           2013-12-09 
O1      User3      Z           (NullOrEmpty)

O2      User1      Y           2013-12-09      
O2      User2      Z           (NullOrEmpty)        

O3      User1      X           2014-12-08  
O3      User1      Z           (NullOrEmpty)
```

When I insert the the 2 date columns in the unpivot statement, I get an error message, which says, that the Date Column is in conflict with the type of the other columns, which are declared in the unpivot-list

Maybe someone can give me a hint, how to edit the unpivot command for this expected case.

Answer (score 2):

I'd actually suggest using CROSS APPLY to unpivot the multiple columns together.  Using CROSS APPLY with UNION ALL or VALUES was made available starting in SQL Server 2005.

The logic will be similar to the following using `UNION ALL`:

```
select 
  t.object, 
  c.Username,
  c.Role,
  c.Date
from yourtable t  -- or query
cross apply
(
  select 'X', User_RoleX, RoleX_Date union all
  select 'Y', User_RoleY, RoleY_Date union all
  select 'Z', User_RoleZ, null
) c (Role, UserName, Date);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5df9c/1). If you need additional filtering, then you could include a WHERE clause.

If you are want to use the VALUES clause, then you would use:

```
select 
  t.object, 
  c.Username,
  c.Role,
  c.Date
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  values
    ('X', User_RoleX, RoleX_Date),
    ('Y', User_RoleY, RoleY_Date),
    ('Z', User_RoleZ, null)
) c (Role, UserName, Date);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5df9c/3). Both give a similar result:

```
| OBJECT | USERNAME | ROLE |                            DATE |
|--------|----------|------|---------------------------------|
|     O1 |   User 1 |    X | December, 08 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|     O1 |   User 2 |    Y | December, 09 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|     O1 |   User 3 |    Z |                          (null) |
|     O2 |   (null) |    X |                          (null) |
```

Comment: thank you very much for your effort, but my requirement changed so the topic can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use existing result as CTE and then use union..

```
With X as 
(
  -- current statement
)
Select Object, UserName, Role, RoleX_Date as Date
From X
Union All
Select Object, UserName, Role, RoleY_Date as Date
From X
```

The result will not be exactly what you wrote you expect.. But I do not really get logic behind results. This might give some idea though..

Comment: thank you very much for your effort, but my requirement changed so the topic can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to un-pivot (or pivot) two times or even multiple times, the easiest way is to concatenate the columns you are going to unpivot with a delimiter in between:

```
Select Column1, Column2 + '|' + Column3 From Table
```

In the result you can easily split the concatenated columns ...